# SQL update id in table except rows with duplicate data in column

Tags: sql, sql-update, distinct-values

I have a table with 3 columns:

- department_id - foreign key
- idcatitem(primary key) - bound with department_id (diferrent department can have same values)
- date

I need to update `department_id` from 57 to 54, but only in rows where values in `idcatitem` are distinct. Is there any easy way to do so ?

NOW:

```
department_id | idcatitem | date
--------------+-----------+------------
    57        |  11288    | 1.1.2020 
    57        |  11323    | 19.12.2019   
    54        |  11323    | 8.2.2012 
    54        |  12200    | 1.1.2016
    57        |   3021    | 2.6.2017
```

What I need:

```
department_id | idcatitem | date
--------------+-----------+------------
     54       |  11288    | 1.1.2020
     57       |  11323    | 19.12.2019
     54       |  11323    | 8.2.2012
     54       |  12200    | 1.1.2020
     54       |   3021    | 2.6.2017
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.) Also take a look at [mcve].

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: `idcatitem` can't be the primary key in your example - by definition it can never contain duplicate values

Answer (score 1):

I am interpreting your question as saying that you have a composite primary key on `(department_id, idcatitem)`.

In standard SQL, you can express your logic using filtering in the `where` clause:

```
update t
    set department_id = 57
    where department_id = 54 and
          not exists (select 1
                      from t t2
                      where t2.department_id = 57 and
                            t2.idcatitem = t.idcatitem
                     );
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a column idcatitem which is primary key then it should be unique right how it would be duplicate in primary key column
please could you elaborate more
Thank you